# I want to understand how to build a code in python to resolve this?

Tags: python, xcode

I'm looking to create code in python to make program done this. So I need to create a program with prefixes: "JKLMNOPQ" and suffixes: "ack" that have output: 
Jack
Kack
Lack
Mack
Nack
Oack
Pack
Quack

Thank a lot.

Comment: what did you try ? post some code you have done

Comment: You can start by going to python.org and reading basic information, then if you have trouble, post a question with exactly what trouble you have.

Comment: "Quack" or "Qack"?

Answer (score 3):

an easy way :

```
>>> l = "JKLMNOPQ"
>>> s = "ack"
>>> result = [i + s for i in l]
>>> result
['Jack', 'Kack', 'Lack', 'Mack', 'Nack', 'Oack', 'Pack', 'Qack']
```

@Alex.S to solve the question of "Qu" :

```
>>> l = "JKLMNOPQ"
>>> s = "ack"
>>> result = [i+s if i!='Q' else i+'u'+s for i in l]
>>> result
['Jack', 'Kack', 'Lack', 'Mack', 'Nack', 'Oack', 'Pack', 'Quack']
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner (too simplistic if Qack should be Quack though):

```
list(map(lambda x: x + 'ack', "JKLMNOPQ"))
```